# Flex Lexer pattern matching sentence separator / punctuation as URL path part

Tags: c++, regex, flex-lexer

I am about to refactor a whitespace tokenizer for text snippets using RE-Flex (flex compatible lexer)

I have the following patterns in my lexer file, I only list those that are involved in this problem:

```
// ...

WHITESPACE  \r\n|[ \r\n\t\f]
DOMAIN      "mil"|"info"|"gov"|"edu"|"biz"|"com"|"org"|"net"|"arpa"|"de"|[a-z]{2}
DIGIT       [0-9]
LETTER      [a-zA-Z]
SYMBOL      ({LETTER}|{DIGIT})({LETTER}|{DIGIT}|"_"|"-")*
BARE_URL    {SYMBOL}("."{SYMBOL})*"."{DOMAIN}
URL_PATH    ([!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#_.~]|"-"|"["|"]"|{LETTER}|{DIGIT})+

%%

("." | "?" | "!" | ";")+ { 
     return tokenizer_base::TK_PUNCTUATION; 
}

/* ... other patterns ... */

{BARE_URL} { 
    return tokenizer_base::TK_BARE_URL;
}
(("http"|"https"|"ftp")"://")?{BARE_URL}{URL_PATH}? { 
    return tokenizer_base::TK_FULL_URL;
}    

/* ... */

/** Ignore the rest */
.|{WHITESPACE} { 
    ;
}

%%
```

This is basically working fine, but consider this case of input:

```
Please visit http://www.google.de.
```

The last `.` in above string is a sentence separator and should return as `TK_PUNCTUATION` token type. Unfortunately it doesn't, its interpreted as a part of `TK_FULL_URL` token and returns as `http://www.google.de.`.

Thinking normal regex I tried to append `[^!;.]` to the `TK_FULL_URL` pattern but this does not work.

Another - in my view hackish - solution would be to analyze the returned token's last
character and `unput` the character back to the input stream if it matches a punctuation symbol. I could do something like this:

```
size_t last = YY_SCANNER.ptr_matcher()->size() - 1; // similar to YYleng
std::string last_str = YY_SCANNER.ptr_matcher()->text(); // similar to YYtext

try {
    // Check if last character is a '.' and second-last char of type alpha
    if (last_str.at(last) == '.' && ::isalpha(last_str.at(last - 1))) {
        YY_SCANNER.ptr_matcher()->unput(last_str[last]); 
        YY_SCANNER.ptr_matcher()->less(last); // similar to YYless
    }
} catch(const std::out_of_range& e) {
    // we keep silent 
}
```

This is working so far but I consider this not very elegant and error-prone.

So my basic question is if I can somehow adjust the urlpath pattern so that a last `.` is not considered as part of a URL path? I am aware that `http://www.domain.tld/foo/bar/.` is valid, but `http://www.domain.tld/foo/bar.` is not.

Perhaps there is a simple solution. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but could you determine that the `.` appears at the end of line (`$`) for your case? Or at least is followed by another whitespace.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Good point, but afaik the `$` would mark the end of the entire lexer input stream so there would be no effect if that very sentence snippet is somewhere in middle of the string. Perhaps the dot/whitespace combination may work, but is think that is rather an unstable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really important to be absolutely clear about what you want to accept. Otherwise, you cannot write a regular expression to accept it, and neither can anyone trying to help you.

**Please note: The (broken) URLs in the following paragraphs were deliberately typed like that so that Markdown's recognition algorithm would be evident.**

Both http://www.domain.tld/foo/bar/. and http://www.domain.tld/foo/bar. are valid URLs. But it's common for URL recognizers to avoid matching the trailing `.` (as you can see, Markdown won't match it) because of the common practice of writing a URL at the end of a sentence, even like this http://www.domain.tld/foo? (But with http://www.domain.tld/foo?search, Markdown recognizes the `?` as part of the URL.)

Parentheses and quotes are also tricky. Markdown, to continue the running example, will accept parentheses in a URL if they are balanced (http://foo.es/?q=(main())) but as you can see, it is still possible to put the URL inside of parentheses. This behaviour is not possible to emulate with a regular expression, since regular expressions can't count.

But let's keep it simple. We can just accept a URL, but exclude the last character if it is in a list of punctuation characters. So that might end up with something like this:

```
URL_CHAR  [][a-zA-Z0-9*@&=+$/?%#_~|()'"!:;.,-]
URL_FINAL [][a-zA-Z0-9*@&=+$/?%#_~|-]
URL_PATH  {URL_CHAR}*{URL_FINAL}
```

A note on the character classes: In a character class, you can use <kbd>]</kbd> as a regular character if you put it at the beginning. So `[][…]` is the conventional way of writing character classes with brackets. <kbd>-</kbd> can be written as the first or last character, so you could write `[-…]` or `[…-]` to include a dash, but if you also have a `]`, you need to put the dash at the end because the beginning is already occupied. So you end up with `[][…-]` which is how I wrote the above patterns. Other than <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>\</kbd>, there are no special characters inside a character class. So you can freely include characters which would otherwise be regex metacharacters, like <kbd>|</kbd>. Other than that, I tried to write the classes so that it is evident which characters are missing from the second class.

If you wanted to recognize `http://www.domain.tld/foo/.` as a URL (as opposed to the more likely http://www.domain.tld/foo/ followed by a punctuation mark), you'd need something a bit more complicated, because you'd have to special-case the slashes. That could be done, but, as I said at the beginning, the important thing is to know *exactly* what you want to match.

Comment: Once again thanks for your help. Also, I appreciate your explanation very much! I will keep your suggestions in mind!

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I reverted your edit because I typed those URLs like that deliberately. I wanted to show how Markdown treats the punctuation at the end of each of them. (I put an emboldened note about that into the answer.)